# Inject cookies into controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, mocking, inversion-of-control

Is there any way to inject the cookie dependecy to a controller? Or do i have to write my own interface and wrapper class around the Cookie collection class?

Comment: your question is rather vague, but I'll assume you're talking about dependency injection? If so, what framework are you using?

Comment: I think he's asking about whether you can get a cookie as a parameter to an Action in ASP.NET MVC 3. The answer, as far as I know, is that you can't - you have to get it from the Cookie collection, which is hardly difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no better answered surfaced I just implemented a interface and injected that for concrete scenario and Mocked it for test

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking about whether you can get a Cookie as a parameter to an Action. I don't believe you can do this, so you'll have to hit the Cookie class directly.

What we do in this case (when cookie based data is required by most of the actions in an application) is put a utility method in a Controller base class and then have all our controllers descend from that. Makes it very easy to use the Cookie in an Action, and centralizes the code for extracting it.